# El Capitan: 2 displays but keep dock to Laptop display

Tags: display, dock

Hey I live at 2 different locations, both of which offer an external display at different places on the table. Whereas everything is perfect with the display that is located above the laptop screen (Dock stays on the laptop screen) the other display forces the Dock onto it (off the laptop screen) as it is located left from my MacBook and I think that is the reason why the Dock moves there.

Unticking "Displays have separate spaces" deactivates other stuff like split-view and placing the monitor that is physically on the left to my MacBook above my MacBook in the arrangement window is simply too confusing for me to handle.

Putting the dock to the right is out of question as my "Touchpad mobility" is quite restricted which makes every move to the right side of the screen extremely uncomfortable.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Just wanted to clarify the dock position. Below is the working one where the dock is on the side to the external screen, the one above shows the rather awkward position right now.

[image]

Comment: When you go to the screen preferences which one has the menubar?  You can drag it back to the Laptop display and the dock should now appear there.  The Mac should remember the arrangement next time you attach.  Your description is a little confusing trying to imagine both setups.

Comment: If you move your mouse pointer to the bottom of your laptop display, and then try to move it down a bit further, the dock should move there. Haven't found a way of pinning it there permanently, but at least you can get it where you want reasonably easily each time.

Comment: @bjbk in the arrangement view the menubar is iconized on my MacBook display and it's visible on both displays (one greyed out at a time), no matter where I drag it the dock stays at the very left position, whatever display this is.

Comment: @CupawnTae thanks but I am unable to reproduce this behavior. Does this work when the dock is set to the left side of your screen?

Comment: This is due to the slight overlap. Moving the dock to the bottom or right side is the only solution I am aware of.

Comment: @user2875404 ah, no, doesn't seem to work with that configuration, sorry, didn't realize you had the dock on the left.

Answer (score 1):

As your monitors slightly overlap to the left, the **Dock** moves there.  The only way to change this, to my knowledge, is to move the dock to the bottom.

- Open **System Preferences**
- Select **Dock** settings
- Select the **Bottom** radio button in the *Position on screen:* setting

[image: Dock Settings]

Comment: You can also change this setting by right-clicking the separator icon in the dock.

Comment: Yes, that will also move the dock but not to the position the OP wanted. Thanks for the tip!